# How to make a part of URL as optional in asp.net core 3+ web api and regex route attribute?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using the following regex in route and I want to support these routes

- /en-gb/api/cat/...
- /th-th/api/cat/...
- /api/cat/...

I am not able to support the URL path without locale i.e `/api/cat/...` I tried to put the locale part in my regex as option by using `?`. I tried in regex 101 and tested my regex it works fine (Note [ and { becomes [[ and {{ in .net core API routes)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/{url:regex([[a-zA-Z]]{{2}}-[[a-zA-Z]]{{2}})?}/api/cat/")]
public class CatApiController : ControllerBase
```

This looks like a basic usecase, but I am not able to figure it out. Can someone please help guide me on this.

EDIT -

`[Route("{locale?}/api/cat/")]`

I also try this, but it does not work for the URL without locale, even after making the locale optional.

Answer (score 0):

> it does not work for the URL without locale, even after making the locale optional

You can try to define multiple routes as below.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/cat")]
[Route("{locale?}/api/cat")]
public class CatApiController : ControllerBase
{
    //...
```